# Can i use swagger to create common response structure?

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

I have common response structure for successful response:

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "response": <data is here>
}
```

and error response:

```
{
  "status": "error",
  "message": "<error description>"
}
```

How can i describe it using Swagger without copy/paste root structure for successful response.

Example of data:

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "response": {
    "name": "Loki",
    "age": 1100
  }
}
```

Comment: JSON reference ($ref) ?

Comment: @esp How can i set the external model? I need to change the contents of a single parameter (`response`) for each request. Can you give an example?